# Multiples consultas con Volley Android-Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy intentando realizar una petición get con volley, no tengo ningún problema realizando una única petición pero ahora quisiera realizar varias peticiones a la misma url cambiando una parte de la url, no se cual sea la forma correcta de realizarlo pero se me ocurrio colocarlo dentro un ciclo for, tengo lo siguiente:

```
private void volley(){
if(lista.size()>0){
        for (int i = 0;i<lista.size();i++){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            String x = lista.get(i).getIdInfo();
            String url = "https://query.example/id=" + x;

            StringRequest getRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONObject IdInfo = jsonObject.getJSONObject("idinfo");
                        JSONObject m = IdInfo.getJSONObject(x);
                        Price1 = df.format(m.getDouble("price1"));
                        Price2 = df.format(m.getDouble("price2"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Valores.add(0,Price1);
                    Valores.add(1,Price2);
                    ListVal.add(Valores);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                  
                }
            });
            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(getRequest);
        }
    }   
}
```

"lista" contiene 2 filas con el valor del id que requiero cambiar en el url.

En la cadena url el string que muestro en el codigo es solo para el ejemplo.

Se espera que la Lista "ListVal" guarde 2 valores por cada fila:

```
 [70.00, 66.50]
 [51.50, 40.90]
```

Pero lo que devuelve es el valor de la ultima consulta GET en las 2 filas:

```
[51.50, 40.90]
[51.50, 40.90]
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar seria de mucha ayuda, realmente no se cual es la forma correcta para lograr este problema al realizar varias solicitudes get.

Answer (score 0):

Cada vez que realizas peticiones guardas los valores en el ArrayList `ListVal`, en este caso el problema no debe ser realizar múltiples peticiones ya que cada una se realiza en un hilo diferente, el problema se debe a lo que responde la petición:

```
  String x = lista.get(i).getIdInfo();
  String url = "https://query.example/id=" + x;
```

Debes asegurar 2 cosas:

- El valor de `lista.get(i).getIdInfo()` es diferente al realizar la iteración.
- Si el valor `lista.get(i).getIdInfo()` es diferente al realizar la iteración este debe responder con diferente resultado.